# Can't found <CoreTelephony/CTMessageCenter.h>

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm creating an sms app and I want to import `<CoreTelephony/CTMessageCenter.h>`, but xcode can't found it.

Update:

Because I want to implement this function `[[CTMessageCenter sharedMessageCenter] sendSMSWithText:@"message" serviceCenter:nil toAddress:@"123456789"];`

Comment: import `CoreTelephony` framework.

Comment: i tried but CTMessageCenter.h isn't appearing.

Comment: And you've added the `CoreTelephony` framework to your Xcode project?

Comment: Yes, I've added `CoreTelephony`.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, I want to implement this function `[[CTMessageCenter sharedMessageCenter] sendSMSWithText:@"message" serviceCenter:nil toAddress:@"123456"];`

Comment: @user3300758 If you are using Xcode5 then import the library using the new way `@import CoreTelephony;` and then try.